# 64bit library (WIA) load issue

Tags: .net, 64-bit, 32-bit, wia

About a week ago I was able to scan images using my 64bit .net application on Windows 7 x64.
I am now getting an error when the WIA interop library loads saying that it, or one of its dependencies is trying to load a dll in an incorrect format.

This error is usually a x64/x32 issue.

It has worked in the past. I have tried regenerating the interop library from the IDE but it doesn't help.

Photoshop x64 can still aquire images so WIA is actually working.

I don't know what's happened in the interim.

I have been battling for a few hours. Any suggestions?

Regards
Craig.

Comment: what type of app is this? Is IIS involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this happen when:

a.) it is a web app and you are using IIS. You have to tell the app pool to allow 32 bit applications.

b.) You aren't compiling in x86 but in x64. If you are using a 32 bit binary, you have to compile in x86.

Comment: Hi, in this case it was that the IDE had spawned off a project.vshost.exe*32 and a project.vshost.exe. Both hosts were running, and the app was loading the wrong one. After killing project.vshost.exe*32 it worked fine.